# XSLT conditional node selection

Tags: xslt, recursion, menu

Here is my problem. I have a "menu" organized like this:

```
<menutree>
  <menuitem name="Foo">
    <menuitem name="Sub-Foo">
      <menuitem name="Sub-sub-foo1"/>
      <menuitem name="Sub-sub-foo2"/>
      <menuitem name="Sub-sub-foo3"/>
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem name="Other-Sub-Foo">
      <menuitem name="Other-Sub-sub-foo1"/>
      <menuitem name="Other-Sub-sub-foo2"/>
      <menuitem name="Other-Sub-sub-foo3"/>
    </menuitem>
  </menuitem>
  <menuitem name="Bar">
    <menuitem name="Sub-Bar">
      <menuitem name="Sub-sub-Bar1"/>
      <menuitem name="Sub-sub-Bar2"/>
      <menuitem name="Sub-sub-Bar3"/>
    </menuitem>
  </menuitem>
</menutree>
```

And I'm looking for a result like the following, assuming you're in the *Sub-sub-foo1* page.
This is also the output I seek if I'm in the Sub-Foo page, as I want to show which sub-pages I have for the current branch. *Other-Sub-Foo* would show the Other-sub-sub-foo pages.

- Foo

  - Sub-Foo

    - Sub-sub-foo1
    - Sub-sub-foo2
    - Sub-sub-foo3
  - Other-Sub-Foo

Bar

The idea is that the menu will build itself depending on the current context. Each page is referenced in the tree by a "menu" attribute, and at every "page" contained in my XML I parse the menu tree to build the correct menu based on the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="currentPage">Sub-sub-foo1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    Current page: <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage" /><br />
    <ul>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//menuitem[@name=$currentPage]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//menuitem[@name=$currentPage]/.." />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="menuitem">
    <li>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@name=$currentPage">
          <b><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

      <xsl:if test="menuitem">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The inner ul should be inside the li; the closing li should be put after the closing xsl:if tag.

Comment: Oh. Problem with carrying the variable to the menuitem template.

Comment: I get the message that the variable isn't declared.

Comment: @MrZombie: did you declared <xsl:param name="currentPage" /> ? You should provide its value before transformation runtime

Comment: Fixed it somehow, but I couldn't just declare it up front, I do all my transformations in a single go, my XML contains all of the pages, preceded by the menu structure. I probably made some horrible, horrible design mistakes with that work, but still. Getting better, broadening my views, adding to my knowledge... Thanks for the help, man. :)